# Set angular.js url root globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular app that is hosted at my university server.

Because the app is not in domain root (urls are constructed as follows: `university.domain/~<student_id>`) all links and image srcs are broken (angular assumes that it is located in domain root).

My question is: how can I override angular base url so I can still use goodies like ng-href, ng-src etc.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting the AngularJS documentation:

> #### Relative links
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must 
>   either specify the url base in the head of your main html file
>   (`<base href="/my-base">`) or you must use absolute urls
>   (starting with /) everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to
>   absolute urls using the initial absolute url of the document, which is
>   often different from the root of the application.

More here [on the official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

### Example

```
<base href="university.domain/~12345678" />
```

Comment: What if I have one level more in document structure? I.e. I want the url of the app to be ```university.domain/~12345678/app``` ?

I tried setting base href to ```"/~1234/app"``` but all requests are for ```/~1234```.

Comment: Are you just using it for development, or do you actually want to host this to the world? Also, could you set up a fiddle with some code to see?

Comment: I already figured it out, it seems that I had to add slash to the end of the base href. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is one more thing that I had to do. I didn't know that relative urls should have a dot in front of them. So these two things (slash in base href and dot in front of relative links) finally made it work.

Comment: The thing I love about SO is that I get to learn as much from answering questions than I do from asking them, thanks for the solution!

Comment: +1 I'm seeing this answer by accident, searching for something else, and ah, I see that there is this and I used app.constant for this and had to take care of it everywhere... Thanks!